# Convert local time to user preferred timezone and user preferred timezone to GMT

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs

In my application, I am using time zone selection as user preference. While displaying dates I convert local time to user preferred timezone. To convert that I use below method

```
function convertSystemTimeToUserTimeZone(localDateTimeValue){
      var userTimeZoneOffset = 3; //For example purpose
      var newDate = new Date(localDateTimeValue.getTime() + (localDateTimeValue.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000) + (userTimeZoneOffset * 3600000));
      return newDate;
}
```

For ex. I am converting local timezone i.e. IST to user preferred timezone i.e. EST

This is working fine and converting user local system time to his user pref timezone. **(Note: Only date time value is getting changed but timezone is still showing local system timezone)**

Now while sending this date to backend, I need to convert the same to GMT. I am not getting how to convert this returned date to GMT, as when I am doing calculation for GMT conversion it is considering local system timezone (IST) not user preferred timezone setting (EST).

I tried below methods but no luck.

```
console.log(new Date(userTimeZoneDateTimeValue.getUTCFullYear(), userTimeZoneDateTimeValue.getUTCMonth(), userTimeZoneDateTimeValue.getUTCDate(), userTimeZoneDateTimeValue.getUTCHours(), userTimeZoneDateTimeValue.getUTCMinutes(), userTimeZoneDateTimeValue.getUTCSeconds()));
console.log(userTimeZoneDateTimeValue.toUTCString());
```

Comment: ECMAScript Date objects are all UTC at heart, timezones and offsets only matter for display. `date.toLocaleString('default', {timeZone:'America/New_York', timeZoneName:'long'})` should do the job.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function getTimeZone( _add = 0 ) {
  var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset(), o = Math.abs(offset) + _add;
  return (offset < 0 ? "+" : "-") + ("00" + Math.floor(o / 60)).slice(-2) + ":" + ("00" + (o % 60)).slice(-2);
}


var addOffset = 180; // 3 hours
console.log("With offset: ", getTimeZone(addOffset) );

console.log("Without offset: ", getTimeZone() );
```

Comment: Code–only answers aren't helpful. A good answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it.